PhD math interview advice
I am asking for advice on PhD math interviews. I have a good academic background, strong letters of recommendation and previous research experience which has led to publications. However, I am woefully bad at interviews. I get super anxious and just freeze up, often getting mind blanks and being completely unable to articulate my thoughts. Usually I am good at explaining things but under interview pressure I perform dreadfully.
With this in mind, I was wondering if anyone could give some advice about this, together with the things prospective supervisors will be looking for, so that I don't slip up too much (if I know what they're looking for, I will be more confident!)

When I was in charge of admissions to my (mathematics) deepartment's Ph.D. program (late 1990's),  no interviews were required. As far as I know, that's still the case (at least for pure math), and I believe the same is true at many other universities.

Your question appears to ask about two different things. The first, and in my view more minor issue, is what you might expect in an interview for a PhD in mathematics ("the things prospective supervisors will be looking for"). The second issue, namely how to deal with the problem that you "... get super anxious and just freeze up" is more significant. It's worth addressing them separately.
Other contributors have answered the first question here, and I think you should read both that answer and consider searching for appropriate combinations of the tags "[phd] [mathematics] [graduate-admissions] [interview]".
I believe, however, that in the long term, the problem  --- of getting super anxious and freezing up  --- is more serious in that it is something that will come back to bite you in many different contexts in your future life (post PhD admissions interview) unless you are able to overcome it. One could imagine this affecting you even if you have ideas about what to expect in an interview ... and then something different happens!
You might not know that the general term among health professionals for the problem you describe is "performance anxiety". Depending on the severity and generality of your problem, there are different solutions, ranging from self-help (in the form of reading, etc.) to professional assistance from a psychologist with expertise in treating anxiety disorders.
You might find it helpful to do a web-search for "performance anxiety", and then to decide on the best course for you in overcoming the freezing problem.
Best of luck with your interview!
